# Change vega lite density plot color on hover/selection

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to highlight the area or line of a density plot on hover and therefore added a mouseover single selection and conditional color encoding.

This works fine for [standard line charts](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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), but doesn't for [line charts based on a density transform](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvSlU3Co2Sx5ilQF91ESAHdGmlmekAGfzdcZEZqfD9A4Mg8I3QlWAAzbiNUbABtDQhQCFytZATmAE8zSABJAFkAEQAhAH0AJR1GJWo1LNzIdnjNLx9EM386AGYO5w0AXWiMIwBrUoklZHb3AvhuTRa2-Q7IAA8zHLyoRLsxTVKKdDFWZeC8mOYxZZxy6pqwJrwtleOYosILygAEdWPFvrpvlRIGN7lASjtjiczhdXpoCrBir8HngAUDIKDwcxmtDYbt1mIUocOu4rjd8UZkBc4e51kpNt9lGZMkjsjS-rBkM94JyVK9EDZkEZsbzIHTbqVqIyCjDeWBxkiJmMNK4NJBBcLRdSHhKqNLEX9cYDSpjWs8ZatUIRcaUlMo7vzIFzXtZWILJdLtRBxuMgA).
In contrast to the standard line chart, the `vgsid` value in the selection store is also null.

I also tried to change the mark type to `circle` and `area` but neither were colored.

Is there an extra step needed in this case?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Vega or Vega-Lite – you probably won't find any answer here. I'd suggest filing a bug report on the Vega-Lite package: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thought so too. I'll file a bug. Thx!

Comment: Issue as reference: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5748